# Using NLog in Winform application - protecting email password

Tags: winforms, nlog

I am incorporating Nlog into a winform application.  I have been able to successfully configure targets and rules by xml and programmatically (C#).  What I wish to do is define the targets and rules in xml but protect my password for the gmail target.  How can I define some targets in XML and add a gmail target programmatically?  Or how can i add supplemental info - ie username and password to a target defined in xml?

Is there a way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Protecting an email password when using NLog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621350/protecting-an-email-password-when-using-nlog)

Comment: I have seen and implemented the info posted in that item.  Being that this is a winform application the app.config cannot be encrypted, as pointed out in that question.  I can do it all in code but rather have some of the targets configurable in XML.  What I seek is a hybrid of the 2 and the other question does not illustrate that.  Let's face it - XML is easier.  How can I modify in code a target defined in the XML config so I can add programmatically, the password?

Answer (score 0):

You can add to, edit or remove any xml/config defined targets in runtime via `LogManager.Configuration`.

So I can imagine you defining some of your targets in xml (e.g. File or Console) and add an email target via code with the encrypted password. Or maybe even define the email target but set the property 'password' of the email target programmatically.